# How to hydrate child object from an inner join?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

so I have this linq syntax query:

```
var parents = (from p in session.Query<Parent>()
              from c in p.Children
              where c.Name == "John"
              select p).ToList()
```

which results in a select statement like this (shortened for brevity):

```
select p.*
from Parents p
inner join Children c
   on p.Id = c.ParentId
where c.Name = 'John'
```

the problem I'm having with this is that although is doing an inner join to children, it is not hydrating the collection, which i need hydrated.

If I change the code to this:

```
var parents = (from p in session.Query<Parent>()
              from c in p.Children
              where c.Name == "John"
              select p).FetchMany(p => p.Children).ToList()
```

the sql statement is created with a second join (left outer join) to the Children table. How do I tell nhibernate to hydrate the Parent entity with all the Children without creating another join?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Parent> parents = Session.Query<Parent>().Fetch(p=> p.Children).ToList();
```

Assuming you have a Children collection in the parent with one to many relation.

For more example checkout this [EagerLoadTests.cs](http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate.Test/Linq/EagerLoadTests.cs?view=log)

Comment: I forgot to mention that i'm filtering by the children's name, so i need to join beforehand, i edited the question